# how to become a mediocre solidity dev

Tags: solidity

i just need to understand how it works and be able to create some simple apps for fun.

i am currently doing cryptozombies, but have the impression that it doesn't incentivize me to experiment with the whole stack. also used remix to deploy a simple contract, but it feels that there's a lot more than that. now i'm exploring vscode and hardhat but still lacking examples to start with.

whats the fastest way to become a mediocre sol dev?

Comment: Why mediocre solidity dev? Solidity is a small part of being a blockchain developer. Learning just solidity is not enough. Nobody will trust a mediocre developer a contract that handles billion of dollars in crypto.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but here's a list of resources that might help you: [awesome solidity](https://github.com/bkrem/awesome-solidity)